# Huge amount of unicode in my document after running

Tags: errors

I just installed TeX Live for the first time and tried to get it running.

By default it was set to pdfLaTeX so I kept that, then I put

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

into the editor and pressed CTRL + T. After that, it opened a window and showed me the PDF with "Test" in it like I desired. However, it also updated my file and removed the above and replaced it with nonsense [like this](http://prntscr.com/mx21we) (I would copy and paste it but it won't paste all of it, [here's a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TpuCfw6E) of what I could paste).

I don't understand how I could've messed it up so badly when all I did was click Custom Install and remove the languages I didn't need then installed it and ran that.

Could someone please help me figure out what's going on here?

I'm on Windows 10 by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Which editor did you use? How did you compile? Via editor or with using the terminal and typing `pdflatex mwe.tex`?

Comment: That's a common error that can catch me out in my cad software etc. You may have opened the PDF (output) so either you "opened" the wrong file in the editor part not viewer part it should be .tex for the editor file open  OR Worse you overwrote your .tex file with the PDF output, that would be disastrous  if at the end of a years thesis (learn to back up your hard won sources)

Comment: I can reproduce this effect if I edit `file.pdf` (instead of `file.tex`), and then run `pdflatex file.pdf`. PdfLaTeX then replaces the original source by its output. If it's the case, don't do that. Keep the TeX source in `file.tex`.